# translate.get sometimes returns key instead of translation

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, ngx-translate

I am currently working on an angular 12 based web application which uses ngx-translate for internationalization and ASP.NET Core 5 for the backend. After adding a component for a new page to the project including routing and everything, it refused to translate anything I wanted it to translate in the new component and just displayed the translation keys instead. After clearing the browser cache, deleting all temporary files of the project and completely recompiling everything, it now seems to work fine. However, there are still a few strange things going on that I just can't explain.
When I add the following line to the `ngOnInit()` method of my new component, it sometimes works fine but sometimes just returns the translation key instead of the translation:

```
console.log("TEST: ", this.translate.instant('login.success'));
```

After taking a look at the documentation, it turns out that the `instant()` method should only be used after ensuring that the translations have been loaded. Alternatively, the documentation mentions that the `get()` method can be used instead to avoid this problem. I tried that but it sometimes still returns the translation key instead of the translation. How is that possible and how can I fix this issue?

The app.module.ts imports:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
...
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
```

The app.component constructor:

```
constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, public translate: TranslateService) {
  translate.addLangs(['en', 'de']);
  translate.setDefaultLang('en');

  const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
  translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|de/) ? browserLang : 'en');
}
```

The app-routing.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/login",
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: "landing",
    component: LandingComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: LandingContentComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "new-component",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./new-component/new-component.module").then(
            (m) => m.NewComponentModule
          ),
      },
      { path: "**", redirectTo: "landing" },
    ]
  },
  { path: "**", component: NotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The new component module:

```
...
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(
    http
  );
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NewComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...

    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      extend: true
    })
  ],
})
export class NewComponentModule { }
```

The new-component.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-component',
  templateUrl: './new-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-component.component.scss']
})
export class NewComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.translate.get('login.success').subscribe((translated: string) => {
      console.log("TEST: ", translated);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you `extend` the `root` translation in the lazy-loaded module, and loading its translation lazily using `TranslateHttpLoader`.

Since the `TranslateHttpLoader` is loading the translation `async`, so it may complete the loading before initializing the component (so you get the translation correctly in this case) or may not, which causes the `this.translate.get` function to fetch the translation from `root` keys and returns the key itself on failed.

So, to resolve this issue you have to make sure that the lazy-loaded translations have been loaded properly before trying to `get/instant` the translation of any keys, and thanks to [Angular Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve), which can be used in similar cases:

> The router waits for the data to be resolved before the route is finally activated.

So we can create our own `resolver` to make sure that the component will not be initialized (since the route will not be activated) until the `observable` of `resolver` has been resolved (completed).

On the other hand, thanks to the `ngx-translate` `getTranslation` function that returns an observable which emit an object of the translation that loaded with the current loader:

> Gets an object of translations for a given language **with the current
> loader** and passes it through the compiler

So the `resolver` will look like the following:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TranslationResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}

  resolve(): Observable<any> {
    return this.translateService.getTranslation(
      this.translateService.currentLang
    );
  }
}
```

And you can include it within the `NewComponentModule` routes under `resolve` like the following:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    resolve: [TranslationResolverService],
    component: NewComponentComponent,
    children: [
      // .....
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I used instant method in services.

I solved it by waiting for the translation to be set up before translating the first time and checking an initialisation flag:

```
export class NotificationService {
  static initialised = false;
    constructor(
      private translateService: TranslateService
    ) {
    }
    if (!NotificationService.initialised) {
      const trans$ = this.translateService.getTranslation( 
      this.translateService.currentLang ).pipe(
        take(1),
        tap(_ => NotificationService.initialised = true),
      );
      const _ = await firstValueFrom(trans$);
      return this.translateService.instant(id);
    }
    return this.translateService.instant(id);
  }
}
```